# Problema simples: Disposição dos Plugins na página

Tags: wordpress

Estou com um problema problema é relativamente simples: estou tentando colocar o plugin do FB comment box para aparecer embaixo do Author Box. A imagem a seguir ilustra o que quero fazer: prntscr.com/hrv5ca

Como faço para inverter a posição dos dois?

Comment: a imagem nao esta aparecendo pode coloca-la novamente

Comment: Já tentou ir no arquivo ``single.php`` e mudar a ordem que esses códigos estão ?